# How would I reduce the repetitiveness of this method?

Tags: java, applet, japplet

Here is the code I am working on(Its part of the CalculatorTester Class which is an extension of the Calculator Class):

```
 if (choice == 1) //Addition
    {
        System.out.println("Math Operation: Addition."); 
        System.out.println("Enter First Number."); 
        int a = in.nextInt(); 
        System.out.println("Enter Second Number."); 
        int b = in.nextInt(); 
        int endValue = c1.addition(a, b); 
        System.out.println("The Sum is: " + endValue + "."); 
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
          ...More Code Here...
    }//end of if()
```

The addition method inside the Calculator object:

```
   public int addition(int a, int b)
   {
       endValue = a + b; 
       return endValue; 
   }//end of method addition()
```

How would I reduce the Repetitiveness of the if Statements, as I have 5 in total due to the amount of different operations one can choose from?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see much repetitive code here. The only thing I can think of is to have a method to get the two number inputs, if all the input code is the same. i.e., the code that starts with `System.out.println("Enter First Number."); ` and ends with `int b = in.nextInt();`, perhaps putting that in a method, that returns, hm an int[2] array?

Comment: Okay, I just saw that your doing the same thing over and over again in the if statements. Just changing the Name of the Operation

Comment: Since your text output will be different depending on the operator, there is not really much redundancy there. I'd go the opposite way and embrace this with even more specific messages, such as "Enter the second factor" "Enter the addend" ... That way, you could also check for division by zero and re-prompt.

Comment: http://ideone.com/89n56T , not exactly the code you have and maybe "too advanced" if you've just started, but you can use objects to represent a choice and let each object implement the parts that are specific to it differently. related: http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask for numbers before and give results after:

```
//user selects operation
System.out.println("Enter First Number."); 
int a = in.nextInt(); 
System.out.println("Enter Second Number."); 
int b = in.nextInt(); 

int endValue;
if (choice == 1) //Addition
    endValue = c1.addition(a, b); 
else if (choice == 2)
    endValue = c1.subtraction(a, b); 
else
    //throw exception since there was no endValue calculated

System.out.println("The result is: " + endValue + ".");
```

You can also use a `switch`/`case` instead of `if`/`if else`/`else`.

Comment: Note that it now says "result" instead of "sum", which is reduced user experience. And five operations are mentioned, I guess one of them could be "sqrt" or "sqr" or "negate", none of which need two operands.

Answer (score 1):

Use a switch statement.

```
switch(choice) {
case 1:
//code for if the choice 1
break;
case 2:
//code for if the choice is 2
break;

//do this for the rest of your choices

}
```

A switch is basically a bunch of if and else if statements.

Remember to add a break statement, if you don't, it keeps executing until it reaches one. (called "falling through")